# Form available in two languages

Tags: php

I'm using php. I have a form which fields are in french. I'd like to know how can I make the form avalaible also in english and let the user choose the language. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: How is your form rendered? Is it hard-written in HTML, or does PHP have a word in the form's generation?

Comment: In which case, can you show the code the generates your form? Edit your question to include that (click the [edit] button).

Comment: @Truth lmao on the "(click the edit button)" ... I guess you never can be too specific with people :)

Comment: @rdlowrey You're not here as long as me, I've seen people posting answers to their own questions with code, and trying to fit it in the tiny comment area. That's why I'm specific with new users. With someone like you with ~150 reputation, I wouldn't be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form is not too large use javascript to toggle visibility of labels and messages.
If you still want PHP use arrays

```
<?php
// Here you asign a default language
if (! isset($_GET['lang']) $_GET['lang']="en";
// Here is your bilingual vocabulary
$arr = array(
"fr" => array("setName"=>"Saisissez votre nom: ")
,
"en" => array("setName"=>"Input your name: ")
);
?>
```

And your form:

```
<!-- Here is your language switch -->
<a href="?lang=fr">Francais</a> | 
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>
```

You can use also AJAX to switch language but we are going too far :)